# query.skip() does not work with Push installation

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to send a push notification (with Parse) to some clients by using a query on Installation objects. I'm using something like this:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
query.equalTo('myattribute', myvalue);
query.descending('updatedAt');
query.skip(1);

Parse.push.send({
    where: query,
    data: {
        alert: 'Hello!'
    }
});
```

Basically I'm just trying to send the push to everyone that matches myattribute === myvalue, and skip the one that was updated last, but it seems that the .skip() is not working, as I am always sending to all the installations that match myattribute === myvalue. I tried just doing a regular query (`query.find()`) and it works as expected. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer over there at parse.com/help. Apparently both the skip and limit parameters are ignored when used in a push query, in order to target all the installations that would match the query without the need to page through results.

So what I did was filtering my objects through some other query and then did a `matchKeyInQuery(myattribute, myattribute, innerQuery)` to get the correct installations for the push.